# Functional analysis associated question

Tags: functional-analysis

Let, {an} be a sequence of complex numbers such that {an*xn} is a p summable sequence for all p summable sequence {xn}; where 1<=p< infinity.
Then prove that {an} is a bounded sequence.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please show your attempts!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You may want to look at how to ask a good question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and how to use mathematical-formatting here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.